# Android Deep link (intent filter) data size limit?

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, url-scheme

I'm using intent filter to deep link to another app also passing data querystring syntax as below:

`myappscheme://com.domain.myappname/receivingIntent?data=MY_DATA_HERE`

This works as expected. Since I pass the data in query string I was wondering whether are there a size limit as it following [URL scheme (GET query string limits)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/812962/240255)

Thought apps are not same as browser, I just want to be sure whether any limits. I did go through android documentation on [Deep linking /](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)  but no mention about size.

P.S:

- I own both the app (not to worry about integrating any 3rd party applications)
- The app i'm building is not native (using Kony). It supports only this way of sharing so I don't have other options.
- I've tested with 64k string on emulator and worked as expected.

Comment: i have no experience with Kony, but doesn't it support a ContentProvider?

Comment: @pskink Their official stance is "No" for ContentProvider. But my question is about any limits in case of native.

Comment: The limit might be the one defined by Android's Uri implementation or maximum Bundle size.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my own unverified answer, as I didn't proceed further with this activity.

As Simon's comment above, as per Android doc on bundle size limit

> When sending data via an intent, you should be careful to limit the
>   data size to a few KB. Sending too much data can cause the system to
>   throw a TransactionTooLargeException exception.

From: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles

> During a remote procedure call, the arguments and the return value of
>   the call are transferred as Parcel objects stored in the Binder
>   transaction buffer. If the arguments or the return value are too large
>   to fit in the transaction buffer, then the call will fail and
>   TransactionTooLargeException will be thrown.
>
> The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb,
>   which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process.
>   Consequently this exception can be thrown when there are many
>   transactions in progress even when most of the individual transactions
>   are of moderate size.

From: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException